# How to open/load asp.net downloaded projects in Visual Studio 2013 without .sln or .csproj file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, web-applications

I'm a beginner at asp.net. I've downloaded a few projects of asp.net but several of them don't contain the .sln file or the .csproj file to run them on MS Visual Studio 13. 
Question is **how can I open/load downloaded projects on Visual studio 2013** and modify to my own needs. I've tried but couldn't find anything relevant. Any youtube link/step by step guide will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have a project file, then you don't have a complete VS project.  Without it, they are just a collection of files and VS won't know how to open them...

Comment: Is not possible to create a new project and add the files to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .sln and .csproj files are necessary for VS to perform many actions because they specify important configuration info like compilation instructions, debug settings, etc.

If you need to build the projects using Visual Studio, then you're going to need those files. Since you don't have those presently, it stands to reason that you could create new ones. Create a new ASP.Net project in Visual Studio, select the options that best fit what you're trying to do, and then add the downloaded files to your new solution/projects.

EDIT: or, if you're opening a website, do as SouXin recommended in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

If they don't. It's most probably means that they are web-site. To open them: In VS File->Open->Web Site (OR Shift-Alt-O)

BTW when you open as Web Site solution file will be created automatically.